# Browser debugger to stop automatically at the line of code (Not knowing where the line of code is) as soon as any javascript fires

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have the browser debugger (firebug or chrome) to break (stop at the executing line of code) as soon as any javascript code fires? **(Not knowing where the line of code is)**  I know about break points. I just need the debugger to stop **automatically** at the place when a line of javascript executes

Answer (score 0):

there is button for that   press Pause button on the firebug panel on left below the firebug two yellow vertical lines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [breakpoint](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Script Tab in firebug, and click on the left of the line you want to put a break point at

[image]

If you need to stop the curent javascript execution (without knowing what's running), press the pause button:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on my original question. **(Not knowing where the line of code is)**  I know about break points. I just need the debugger to stop **automatically** at the place when a line of javascript executes

Comment: I don't understand `at a place when a line of javascript executes` and `I don't know which line`. So you want your javascript code to stop wherever it's executing when you click like a button or something ?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[How to set breakpoints in inline Javascript in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156388/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-inline-javascript-in-google-chrome-browser-for-linux)

and this answer (for Chrome):
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

and finish up with this one for some interesting tips:
http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/25-dev-tool-secrets/

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on my original question. **(Not knowing where the line of code is)**  I know about break points. I just need the debugger to stop **automatically** at the place when a line of javascript executes

Comment: You mean, write something into your javascript that trips the debugger? I don't know that you can do that, without writing an actual error into your script, and turning on the various debugger's "pause on exception" feature. Firebug lets you do that, and so does Chrome.