# chrome console find fired event

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

What is the console function I can do in the Chrome console that would set a global break point?  For example could I execute something like

```
console.scf()
function scf(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // show all events / methods attempting to fire.
}
```

so a global break-point then that would point to the file / line number.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5156526/475125