# JavaScript no response with validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I am attempting to create a simple form validation. When I hit the submit button nothing happens. I have been looking at examples for a while and I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong. Any suggestions:

Right after this post I am going to break it all down and start smaller. But in the meantime I figured another set of eyes couldn't hurt and it is very possible I am doing something horribly wrong.

HTML:

```
<form name="form" action="index.html" onsubmit="return construct();" method="post">
    <label>Your Name:<span class="req">*</span> </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  /><br />
    <label>Company Name:<span class="req">*</span> </label>
    <input type="text" name="companyName" /><br />
    <label>Phone Number:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="phone" /><br />
    <label>Email Address:<span class="req">*</span></label> 
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <label>Best Time to be Contacted:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="TimeForContact" /><br />
    <label>Availability for Presenting:</label> 
    <input type="text"  name="aval" /><br />
    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" ROWS="3" COLS="30"></textarea>
    <label>First Time Presenting for AGC?:<span class="req">*</span></label> 
    <input type="radio" name="firstTime" value="Yes" id="yes" /><span class="small">Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="firstTime" value="No" id="no"/><span class="small">No</span><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function construct() {
    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    var companyName = document.forms["form"]["companyName"].value;
    var email = document.forms["forms"]["email"].value;
    var phone = document.forms["forms"]["phone"].value;
    var TimeForC = document.forms["forms"]["TimeForContact"].value;
    var availability = document.forms["forms"]["aval"].value;

    if (validateExistence(name) == false || validateExistence(companyName) == false)
        return false;
    if (radioCheck == false)
        return false;
    if (phoneValidate(phone) == false)
        return false;
    if (checkValidForOthers(TimeForC) == false || checkValidForOthers(availability) == false)
        return false;
    if (emailCheck(email) == false)
        return false;
}
function validateExistence(name) {
    if (name == null || name == ' ')
        alert("You must enter a " + name + " to submit! Thank you."); return false;
    if (name.length > 40)
        alert(name + " is too long for our form, please abbreviate."); return false;
}

function phoneValidate(phone) {
    if (phone.length > 12 || phone == "" || !isNaN(phone))
        alert("Please enter a valid phone number."); return false;
}

function checkValidForOthers(name) {
    if (name.length > 40)
        alert(name + " is too long for our form, please abbreviate."); return false;
}

function messageCheck(message) {
    var currentLength = name.length;
    var over = 0;
    over = currentLength - 200;

    if (name.length > 200)
        alert(name + " is too long for our form, please abbreviate. You are " + over + " characters over allowed amount"); return false;
}

function radioCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById("yes").checked == false || document.getElementById("no").checked == false)
        return false;
}

function emailCheck(email) {
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Am I calling my functions incorrectly? I honestly am not sure where I am going wrong. 
I don't understand how to debug my code... I am using chrome and I am not receiving any errors in the console. Is there a way to set breakpoints to step through the javascript?

I realize i just threw a lot of code up there so thanks in advance for sifting through it.

Comment: You have many issues in your code.  I would suggest you read my answer below and think about how to enable this code so that you can be confident that it works.  The accepted answer is the root of **this** problem, but it is just the beginning of the issues you are going to run into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is mistake:

Replace `var email = document.forms["forms"]["email"].value;`

by `var email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;`

There are lot of places in your js :

var email = document.forms["**forms**"]["email"].value;

var phone = document.forms["**forms**"]["phone"].value;

var TimeForC = document.forms["**forms**"]["TimeForContact"].value;

var availability = document.forms["**forms**"]["aval"].value;

where you mistyped **form** as **forms**.

**Is there a way to set breakpoints to step through the javascript?**

Yes there is a way to set breakpoints:

[image]

Refer following links in order to know the method to set break-point in debugger console in Chrome:

**[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156388/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-inline-javascript-in-google-chrome-browser-for-linux)**

**[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome)**

Answer (score 3):

The following should fix the immediate problem:

```
function construct(form) {
  var 
    name = form["name"].value,
    companyName = form["companyName"].value,
    email = form["email"].value,
    phone = form["phone"].value,
    TimeForC = form["TimeForContact"].value,
    availability = form["aval"].value
  ;
  if (!validateExistence(name) || !validateExistence(companyName)) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (!radioCheck) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (phoneValidate(phone) == false) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (!checkValidForOthers(TimeForC) || !checkValidForOthers(availability)) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (emailCheck(email) == false) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You had a typo in the form `document.forms["forms"]`, where 'forms' doesn't exist. Instead of always traversing objects to get to your form, you can use `this` to pass the current element into your function.

```
<form action="index.html" onsubmit="return construct(this);" method="post">
```

If you're starting out it's also a good idea to make sure you set all your braces (i.e. curly brackets) as this will help you avoid getting confused with regards to alignment and brace matching.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is the `forms` where you meant `form`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FCwYW/)

But you have other problems with your validation code, for example:

```
if (name == null || name == ' ')
```

Here you are checking if `name` is null or name is a single space. I assume you wanted to check if the field is blank, but a completely empty string will evaluate as false in your condition, as will two spaces. What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
if (!name) {
    // tell the user they need to enter a value
}
```

Conveniently (or sometimes not), Javascript interprets null, an empty string, or a string full of white space as false, so this should cover you.

You also have a whole host of other problems, see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FCwYW/2/

Most of the problems have been pointed out by others.

- You need to use braces `{}` when you have more than one line after an
  `if` statement.
- You need to return true when you pass you validation
  tests or Javascript will interpret the lack of a return value as false.
- Your `radioCheck` will only pass if **both** radio buttons are checked.
- You where checking that your phone number was NOT NaN (i.e. it is a number) and returning false if it was.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest learning some new debug skills.  There are ways to break down a problem like this that will quickly isolate your problem:

- Commenting out code and enabling parts bit by bit
- Using a debugger such as Firebug
- Using `console.log()` or `alert()` calls
- Reviewing your code line-by-line and thinking about what it is supposed to do

In your case, I would have first seen if `name` got a value with a `console.log(name)` statement, and then moved forward from there.  You would immediately see that name does not get a value.  This will lead to the discovery that you have a typo (`"forms"` instead of `"form"`).

Some other errors in your code:

- You are returning false outside of your `if` statement in `validateExistence()`:

  ```
  if (name == null || name == ' ')
      alert("You must enter a " + name + " to submit! Thank you."); 
      return false;
  ```

  In this case, you do not have brackets `{}` around your statement.  It **looks** like `return false` is in the `if(){}`, but it is not.  **Every** call to this code will `return false`.  Not using brackets works with a single call, but I don't recommend it, because it leads to issues like this when you add additional code.
- In the same code, you are using `name` as the field name when it is really the value of the field:

  ```
  alert("You must enter a " + name + " to submit! Thank you."); return false;
  ```

  You really want to pass the field name separately:

  ```
  function validateExistence(name, field) {
      if (name == null || name == ' ') {
          alert("You must enter a " + field + " to submit! Thank you."); 
          return false;
      } else if (name.length > 40)
          alert(field + "value is too long for our form, please abbreviate."); 
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```
- You are not calling `radioCheck()` because you are missing parentheses:

  ```
  if (radioCheck == false)
  ```
- In `radioCheck()`, you are using `||` instead of `&&`.  Because at least 1 will always be unchecked by definition, you will always fail this check:

  ```
  if (document.getElementById("yes").checked == false || document.getElementById("no").checked == false) return false;
  ```
- And more...

My suggestion is to enable one check at a time, test it, and once it works as expected, move on to the next.  Trying to debug all at once is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

replace `var email = document.forms["forms"]["email"].value;`

by

```
var email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try With Different Logic**. You can use bellow code for check all four(4) condition for validation like not null, not blank, not undefined and not zero only use this code (!(!(variable))) in javascript and jquery.

```
function myFunction() {
var data;  //The Values can be like as null,blank,undefined,zero you can test

if(!(!(data)))
 {
 alert("data "+data);
 } 
 else 
 {
    alert("data is "+data);
}

}
```