# Breakpoint is not hit on javascript function?

Tags: asp.net

I have marked a debugger point in aspx design[on function]. but it is not hitting

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: You mean to say , you cannot debug but the code is running?

Comment: yes i have mention event handler for the onclient click of button to function on same page in script section but it is not hit.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction()
        { alert("Enjoy....!") };  </script>  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Button :<asp:Button ID="btnPrice" runat="server" OnClientClick="AddEmployee()" Text="Add" />

Comment: Edit your question @SunilJadhav instead of commenting...

Comment: Your function names are different in Onclientclick event

Answer (score 0):

1) Put break point in your correct success code

2) try it with IE browser

3) Check the application run debug mode

**4)Please check the correct function name are called in your button click event .** (need to same function name

More details : [Fixing "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo)

and for Chrome browser : [How to set breakpoints in inline Javascript in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156388/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-inline-javascript-in-google-chrome-browser-for-linux)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use Visual Studio to debug script running in Internet Explorer, you must enable script debugging in Internet Explorer. Script debugging in Internet Explorer is disabled by default.

**To Enable Script Debugging in Internet Explorer**

1. In Internet Explorer,choose Internet Options from the Tools menu.
2. In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
3. On the Advanced tab, under Browsing, clear Disable Script Debugging.
4. Click Ok