# How to store result from POST request to use in another controller in Ionic and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Okay so I am trying to use promises for the first time so bear with me. This question builds upon my question [How to pass results from POST request to another page in Ionic and Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888983/how-to-pass-results-from-post-request-to-another-page-in-ionic-and-angular). In essence I'm doing rudimentary user authentication and I created a service to make post requests to a database to confirm valid login information was entered. What I would like to do is store the response from the POST request in an array that I can later access in my profile page so that I can display the user's information. But I'm having a hard time storing the promise in a variable without messing up the result in the controller (success doesn't print).

controller.js

```
 UserProfile.getProfile(userData).success(function(profile) {
          $scope.uProfile = profile;

          //invaid input
          if ($scope.uProfile == null) {
            alert('Invalid Credentials Entered');

            //refresh the page
            $window.location.reload();
          }
          else {
            var uProfile = $scope.uProfile;
            console.log("success");
            //console.log(uProfile);
           // $state.go('tab.profile',{usrProfile: uProfile}); //Moveto the profile page
          }
```

services.js

```
.factory('UserProfile',function($http) {

  var profileInfo = {};
  var profiles = [];

     return {
         getProfile: function(data) {
          console.log("in service");
           var url = 'https://cs496-app3.herokuapp.com/api/person/login/';
           var obj = {
                'email_address': data.email,
                'password': data.password
            };

         $http.post(url, obj)
          .then(function(result){
            profiles[0] = result;
            console.log(profiles[0]);
            return profiles[0];
          })
         // console.log(profiles[0]);
       }
      };

});
```

When I change my service to simply

```
return $http.post(url, obj)
```

everything works fine but then I can't access the result from the post later on in another controller. How can I store the promise?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your **services.js** with the below code

```
.factory('UserProfile',function($http) {

  var profileInfo = {};
  var profiles = [];
  var getProfile = function(data) {
          console.log("in service");
           var url = 'https://cs496-app3.herokuapp.com/api/person/login/';
           var obj = {
                'email_address': data.email,
                'password': data.password
            };
            $http.post(url, obj)
                        .then(function(result){
                                profiles[0] = result;
                                console.log(profiles[0]);
                /***********removed and placed below********************/
                        })
             return profiles[0];
            // console.log(profiles[0]);
    }
     return {
         getProfile:getProfile
      };

});
```

Explanation : As per your code you have

```
$http.post(url, obj)
          .then(function(result){
                  profiles[0] = result;
                  console.log(profiles[0]);
                  return profiles[0];
})
```

return is inside the then function and it is not returned by the factory method. 
By default angular factory should return one promise. 
So

```
return profiles[0];
```

having it outside the http.post will work out.
The format of your implementation is changed as a good practice but not mandatory