# VS.Code Debugging with a breakpoint in a script inline HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

**Hi There**

In Visual Studio Code, I'm trying to debug/breakpoint a simple HTML file with some JavaScript.

I'm using VS.Code, installed with extension "Live server", and "Debugger for Chrome" to a Google Chrome browser.

The problem is I cannot set any breakpoint in VS.Code HTML-file nor at Chrome DevTools to inspect the code (Says: !--Code injected by live-server--), so is there a wise head, there can help me here ?

**Cheers Jan**

NB: I have looked at this topic, but it doesn't concern VS.Code:
[How to set breakpoints in inline Javascript in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156388/how-to-set-breakpoints-in-inline-javascript-in-google-chrome)

[image: VS.Code - Chrome Browser]

Answer (score 2):

```
"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true
```

Which will let you set breakpoints in any file, valid or not. I haven't tested it yet with HTML files but that might be a good workaround.

See also:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/122

Comment: Seems not to be working any more. VS Code 1.34.0, Debugger for Chrome 4.11.3

Comment: This worked fine for me, once I updated my launch file to point to the right HTML page also.